# IDE0007 Visual Studio error isn't preventing build but won't go away. How do i get rid of it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, stylecop

We just switched from VS 2015 to VS 2017 a week ago, and when I opened the project in 2017, we got all kinds of errors, including but not limited to the following:

IDE0007 - Use var instead of explicit type
  IDE0022 - Use expression body for methods

I don't want these as errors. I want them as suggestions AT BEST. preferably i need them to go away completely. but no matter what i do, i can't fix it. i went into tools -> options -> code style preferences to no avail. I changed them all to "suggestions" but it hasn't changed anything. They're all showing up as suggestions, warnings, AND errors at the same time.

I don't have any extensions installed. I thought maybe resharper, but it isn't there. We've used StyleCop from the start of the project, but it has NEVER complained about these errors, and it never marks them as errors, it always marks them as warnings. I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is configured in the References node of the project.  Open it up and right-click the Analyzers item.  Always "hidden" whenever I looked at it, good setting.

Comment: can you put that as an answer instead of a comment? i fixed it

Comment: You'll have to post the answer yourself, I can't guess why the project did not have the normal default rules in effect.

Answer (score 0):

I re-ran the VS 2017 installer and modified it by adding an extra package (data and analytics). when i brought it back up, it was fixed. not much of an answer, i'm sorry. but a commenter above said that the data to which I'm referring is stored in the references node of the project.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and I was able to hide those kinds of errors by selecting the "Build Only" option from the dropdown in the Error List menu (instead of "Build + IntelliSense", which was showing by default for me)

Here is a screenshot of the ErrorList and dropdown

[image]

EDIT: Unfortunately, the build error underlines still show up on my file. I am trying to resolve that now.